# Subversion subclipse - how to make files outside eclipse projects visible?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

Let's say that under my repository trunk I have one file (script.sh) and two eclipse projects (project1 and project2). I checkout the full trunk and make project1 and project2 visible in eclipse.

My question is: how do I make script.sh visible in subclipse, so that I can update/commit it?

Ideally, I would want to update/commit the whole trunk, not only the projects visible in the Package Explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could create a project from your repository trunk? Eclipse handles this correctly for mvn projects at least, and this would allow you to commit the whole at once. If you don't want the eclipse metadata to be in your repository, add .settings, .classpath and .project in svn:ignore.

Personally I would do that using TortoiseSVN or the command-line client though.

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate SVN repository to contain your `script.sh` and you can update / commit it.